# Nesting functions and performance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, nested-function

Some of coworkers are saying that nesting functions is bad for performance and I wanted to ask about this.

Lets say I have the function:

```
function calculateStuff() {
    function helper() {
    // helper does things
    }
    // calculateStuff does things
    helper();
}
```

helper is a private function that is only used inside calculateStuff. That's why I wanted to encapsulate this inside calculateStuff.

Is this worse performance wise than doing:

```
function helper() {

}

function calculateStuff() {
    helper();
}
```

Notice that in the second case, I expose helper to my scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because performance metrics are best handled by jsperf and have a short shelf-life as browsers evolve.

Comment: Don't ask others about performance. When in doubt, measure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your first code, at each call of `calculateStuff`, a new copy of `helper` will be created.

With your second code, all calls will share the same `helper`, but it will pollute the outer scope.

If you want to reuse `helper` without polluting the outer scope, you can use an IIFE:

```
var calculateStuff = (function () {
  function helper() {
    // helper does things
  }
  return function() {
    // calculateStuff does things
    helper();
  }
})();
```

Comment: You'd still be polluting the outer scope, although it wouldn't be the global scope.

Comment: @MinusFour polluting it with what exactly?

Comment: @MinusFour It creates an intermediate scope and pollutes that instead of the outer one.

Comment: I'm just saying that the intermediate scope could also be considered an outer scope (at least from anonymous function context).

Comment: @MinusFour that makes no sense.

Comment: @MinusFour : I agree with @zerkms; JS only closes over lexical scope -- there is no "pollution" at this level. It is totally unlike global scope pollution.

Comment: @LawrenceDol I was grasping at straws with my use of "pollution" there. I considered the `helper` function logic local to the `calculateStuff` function. Placing the `helper` function outside would have been an implementation leak therefore "polluting" its outer scope. That's as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 13):

In theory, there's a potential performance impact, in that you need to create a new closure context for *helper* every time *calculateStuff* is called (because it might reference variables from the enclosing scope).

I'm *pretty sure* that the JIT compiler in most JavaScript engines should be able to tell that you aren't actually accessing any variables from the parent context, and just skip binding all of those values. I may be missing some edge case where this isn't generally possible, but it seems straighforward-enough.

In any case, we're talking about nanoseconds of overhead per iteration, so unless your code is executed *a lot*, you'd never notice the time difference. If in doubt, profile it and check...

---

I decided to follow my own advice, and profile this [on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/nested-vs-flat-functions), with Safari 9. I used the do-nothing functions as provided in the original question, to highlight the overhead of just calling a nested function:

Nested functions: 136,000,000 calls per second

Flat functions: 1,035,000,000 cals per second

[Oriol's IIFE version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248367/17826): 220,000,000 cals per second

Clearly the flat functions are *much* faster than either of the alternative versions. *However*, think about the magnitude of those numbers - even the "slow" version only adds 0.007 microseconds to the execution time. If you do any kind of calculation or DOM manipulation in that function, it'll absolutely dwarf the overhead of the nested function.

Comment: "to create a new closure context for helper every time calculateStuff is called (because it might reference variables from the enclosing scope)." --- so if it does not refer to any free variables - there is no such impact at all? If that's what you're trying to express, then it's wrong.

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, if it does not reference free variables, and especially if it is not exported from that scope, the function can and will be inlined. How is that wrong?

Comment: @Bergi the standard does not require that. And engines do not guarantee that. "How is that wrong?" --- there is nothing that **GUARANTEES** a function creation is **free**.

Comment: @zerkms: Neither me nor Mark said so. Of course, the standard does not require anything about performance (except ES5 Maps&Sets), but Mark is right that *most* JIT compilers (i.e., actual implementations) are able to skip over creating the function object or even a closure context on the heap.

Comment: @Bergi right, but it implies that binding a lexical scope is the only overhead there. Whereas the function creation in general is not cheap at all. So my point here is that the answer emphasizes on binding of scope and misses an important part of creating a function object.

Comment: @zerkms: In any case, the answer should be upvoted for "*If in doubt, profile it*" alone :-)

Comment: I did this test, just now on Firefox 56 and Chrome 62, both showed that nested is the fastest. Nested, Flat, IIFE - (FF - 706, 655, 415) (Chrome - 642, 118, 117). I don't know if this changed since back then, but it looks like nested functions are actually better for performance now, not to mention providing better lexical scoping, instead of flat, meaningless functions that some people think of good practice and are against nesting.

Comment: Using the jsperf tests I posted above, I get essentially identical results for all three methods with Chrome 83 and Firefox 77, and Nested is still slower for Safari 13. As a side note, the performance results I get for Safari are now 10x worse than Chrome on the same computer, though that doesn't track with actual performance on real-world code. Benchmarking can be tricky...